Outlook Calendar Deletion Doesn't Remove Access for Shared Users: Is This Normal?
I recently encountered an interesting behavior with calendar sharing in Outlook and wanted to see if others have experienced the same issue.
Scenario:

User 1 creates a secondary calendar in Outlook and shares it with User 2, granting User 2 edit permissions.
User 1 then deletes the calendar.

Unexpected Outcome:

User 2 retains access to the calendar with the originally assigned permissions (e.g., edit permissions) even after User 1 has deleted it. User 2 can continue to edit the calendar, create new events, and manage it within those permissions.

User 1, however, won’t receive any notifications or updates if User 2 makes changes to the calendar.

Is this normal behavior in Outlook Calendar?

Is it possible to recover a deleted secondary calendar?

If this is the default behavior, how can User 1 ensure that access to the shared calendar is removed for User 2?


